# Using onDelete cascading

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

im trying to use in my app on delete cascading, and maybe im not doing right but i had the idea when i delete in my case a product automaticlly would be deleted the columns related with it.

My case:

DB:

```
products:
- id_product;
- status;

products_translations:
- id;
- product_id;
- name;
- description;
- locale;
```

My migration that makes the relation and use cascading delete:

```
 Schema::table('product_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Controller where i make the delete product:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
        $product->delete();
        return back();
```

Comment: Are you using soft deletes?

Comment: Are you using softdelete? The registry is not deleted if you are using softdelete.

Answer (score 0):

i advice you to this in other way try to delete based on event. in your product model add this

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($product)
    {
            $product->Translations()->delete();

    });
}
```

remember to add hasMany relation to product model as a public function named `Translations()`

Comment: hello i just added this function based on the event in the model and i also have the Translations "hasMany" relation, but is giving me a error of :
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()

Comment: yes may be because detach is for belongtoMany try `->dissociate()` or just `->delete()`

Comment: delete is how i just made it like in your answer